# mongodb storing incorrect date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I don't really understand why this is happening but in mongodb atlas personalisation settings I have set my time zone to the country I am in. I am hosting the frontend on Netlify and I am using Heroku for my node.js backend.

In my schema I have the date set up like so:

```
  requiredDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
```

On the frontend there is a date picker. If someone was to select a Friday, it always saves in the database as Thursday like below. So, it is always a day behind it would seem, either in hours or days or whatever it is.

```
2020-08-27T22:00:00.000+00:00
```

The date picker field on the frontend sends the date to node.js like so:

```
27/8/2020
```

I tried this which seems to work but isn't there a more global way of doing it than having to do this for every form that has a date in it?

```
let localTime = visitDate.toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: "Asia/Calcutta",
});
```

Comment: You need to convert the time you are storing to UTC before storing it. Some languages/drivers/ODMs may do this for you, if yours doesn't you need to do it manually.

Comment: Sorry, you posted as I updated my question. Is my update what you are referring to?

Comment: See https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-documents/#date-fields and https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/bson-v4/#date-instances for how dates are handled in Ruby and Mongoid. You need to find equivalent documentation for your language and driver, if you can't find the docs you can always test and figure this out the hard way.